# Microservices architecture multi level event buses

Tags: microservices, amqp

Pretty much all documentation on microservices I came across explain just one tiny part of some complex system. I am trying to understand big picture. So my question is: Has anyone expirienced in practice multi level AMQP Event Buses across solution when using microservices? Something like shown in the picture?
[image: Possible architecture]

Or is it better to have just one message broker to handle all PUB/SUB across entire solution?

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 1):

In our enterprise architecture we have one message broker cluster with different types of queues handle the different levels of communication. But that’s just one enterprise.